# Question about noun compound

Tags: nouns, compounds

I need to convert some noun compounds into regular sentences, and I am having trouble with four of them:

1) greatly reduced atmospheric ozone depletion.

2) an airport air traffic controller.

3) air pollutant particle size.

4)  population growth rate

Those are my answers:

1)Greatly reduced depletion in the atmospheric ozone.

2) A controller which controls the traffic in the air at the airport.

4) The rate of growth of a population

And number 3) I don't know how to convert at all.

Are my answers correct?

Comment: (3) The size of the particles of pollutants in the air.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. Are the others correct?

Comment: Why did you want to change the form of the original word groupings? Since they could be used in sentences as easily -- perhaps more easily -- than your solutions, did you have another reason? I ask because your solutions aren't actually sentences. I'm not trying to be obnoxious, just really want to understand your objective.

Comment: @IsabelArcher Those are exercises about noun compound

Comment: It sounds like the goal was to help you practice choosing prepositions, rather than to help you write complete sentences. Is that correct?

Comment: @IsabelArcher Yes. to practice noun compounds prepositions

Comment: Are 1), 2) and 4) correct?

Comment: I'd suggest that you change your question to show that you're not asking to form complete sentences.